# Is server being localhost:3306 an issue? phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

When I access phpMyAdmin from GoDaddy it says the server is localhost:3306 and therefore can only connect to mySQL using localhost as servername.  Should the server be my websites url or ip address?  Do I need to set it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not need to set it up.  The fact that it is showing localhost:3306 in GoDaddy simply shows that it's on the same server with your hosting package.

If you're connecting to this MySQL instance from PHP, you would connect to "localhost" as the server address.  No port should be necessary as 3306 is default for MySQL.

No, the server should not be set up to use your websites url or IP address, as having it at localhost in essence does that.  It's on the same server AS your website.

Does that make sense?

Comment: @aheit - No problem at all :)